# what is the use of trap value?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm a newbie in kerel. In a linux kernel macro definition, I saw a line

```
li r10 trap
```

I would like to know the use of this 'trap' value. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li` is load immediate, r10 is a register, and there should be a comma before `trap` which is going to a macro parameter... if you show the line above without the containing macro, that last insight's lost.  Basically, it's putting one of the macro parameters into CPU register `r10`.  Knowing that by itself is just about useless by the way - you ought to get a tutorial that walks you through things in some systematic way.  E.g. see http://www.linuxchix.org/content/courses/kernel_hacking/lesson7

Comment: Actually, I have some  theoretical tutorials but I need some thing to workout.  Can you suggest a useful tutorial please?.

Comment: @Abin: I don't know anything about what you know, what you consider theoretical or practical, or what you're really trying to achieve, so I can't currently suggest any tutorial.  Anyway, that would be better (and may have already been) asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the register will be used to generate an exception is necessary.